# How to display rails string variable in a new page and save as csv file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, export-to-csv

I'm using Ruby on Rails and I want to display some string in a new page when the user click on a button in my current page.

The string that I will be displaying in the new page is store in this variable called "@csv". I got this @csv variable from my controller.

Currently, my code display a table containing the content of csv and a button. When the user click on that button, a new page should be display in their browser displaying the csv string (content of the table) and allows the user to download it as a csv file.

I want it to work like those pdf files in chrome. We know that when we click on a pdf file in chrome, chrome will display those pdf file in a new tab and allow the user to download it when control + s is pressed. That is what I want. But the problem is that what I have is only a @csv variable in the index.html.erb page, not a csv file.

My code is here:

index.html.rb (inside 'table' folder)

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

    <% @csv.each_line do |line| %>
        <tr>
            <% line.split(",").each do |f| %>
                <th><%= f %></th>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>

</table>

<form action="/export.html" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Export as CSV" >
</form>
```

table_controller.rb

```
class TableController < ApplicationController

    def index
        #Get the search terms first and store it in a variable
        @q = params[:q]
        #create a file that stores the search terms
        fileName = "fileName"   #must be named fileName because I don't know how to pass parameter using %x
        out_file = File.new(fileName, "w")
        out_file.puts(@q)
        out_file.close

        #an executable file named SearchEngine will:
        #1) take a parameter containing the name of the file that contains a string search terms (example: Women over 50)
        #2) stdout (print to terminal) a csv file (line by line, comma separated lines)
        #then I will store the output of the executable in my @csv variable so that I can use it to display the search resultin the table in index.html.rb page
        @csv = %x(SearchEngine fileName)

        #finished using the search term file so I can delete it now
        File.delete(fileName)
    end

end
```

If more information is needed or my question is unclear, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You talking about inline disposition. It's very easy to implement in Rails.

You already have string with csv, so all you need is to send it properly to the browser.

```
def index
  # ...
  @csv = %x(SearchEngine fileName)
  File.delete(fileName)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
      send_data @csv, type: Mime::CSV, disposition: 'inline'
    end
  end
end
```

After that your will be able to access csv in browser by appending `.csv` to the url.

If you need to repeat same process in different places it will be easier for you to create controller renderer for csv and use it everywhere.

```
# config/initializers/controller_renderers.rb
ActionController::Renderers.add :csv do |obj, options|
  filename = options[:filename] || 'data'
  disposition = options[:disposition] || 'inline'
  str = obj.respond_to?(:to_csv) ? obj.to_csv : obj.to_s
  send_data str, type: Mime::CSV, disposition: disposition,
    filename: "#{filename}.csv"
end

# inside your controller action
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { render csv: @csv, filename: "mycsv" }
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, but all the content you post is about the controller and I want to display the csv on a new tab. I don't really understand how to do that using the information you provided.

Comment: @Henry So, you want to provide a link to csv in your view and this link should be opened in new tab, right?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I want. (except that I don't have any csv file currently, I just have a variable that contain a string in csv format, that string also has many '\n' character in it)

Comment: I am able to implement download the csv file now, but I am not able to display it in a new tab. Thank you for the information provided.

Answer (score -1):

I am now able to download the csv once I clicked the Export as CSV button on my view page. But I don't know why that csv file is not display on a new page. I uses inline for the disposition so it should display the csv on a new page. I don't know why it is not doing that.

However, for people who is interested about being able to download a csv file from a variable, the new files looks like below:

table_controller.rb

```
class TableController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @q = params[:q]
        fileName = "fileName"
        out_file = File.new(fileName, "w")
        out_file.puts(@q)
        out_file.close

        @csv = %x(SearchEngine fileName)

        File.delete(fileName)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.csv do
                send_data @csv, type: Mime::CSV, disposition: 'inline', filename: 'csv_search_results.csv'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

index.html.rb (inside 'table' folder)

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

    <% @csv.each_line do |line| %>
        <tr>
            <% line.split(",").each do |f| %>
                <th><%= f %></th>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>

</table>

<%= link_to "Export as CSV", {:action => "index", :format => :csv}, :target => '_blank' %>
```

Comment: A follow up should be either an update in the question or a separate question.